# How to create a CASE or IF nested to change data values in a column

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark, aws-glue-workflow

I need to update data values from a column in aws glue, im looking for something like a CASE sentence or IF ELSE nested.

Example:

```
    CASE WHEN dc.activo = 0 OR dc."max" < 100 THEN 'Inactivo'
WHEN dc.estadoRegistro = 0 THEN 'Activo, registro incompleto, no recibe pagos'
WHEN dc.estadoRegistro = 1 THEN 'Activo, registro completo, recibe pagos'
WHEN dc.estadoRegistro = 2 THEN 'Activo, registro incompleto, recibe pagos'
ELSE 'Otro' END,
```

Thanks for reading :)